# Существует ли API или какая либо библиотека с базой для определения района внутри крупных городов по названию улицы?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, геолокация, геокодирование, кладр

Возникла необходимость доработать CRM чтобы из кладра подставлялась не только информация о городе, регионе, улице, а так же о районе(для крупных городов в котором находится эта улица). В API kladr-api точка ру такой информации не нашёл в API от яндекс(что на поддомене geocode-maps) тоже не увидел. Может быть там есть а я просто не нашёл?

Обратите внимание, мне нужен не район региона(который как раз в кладре есть), то есть город Фурманов в Ивановской области находится в Фурмановском районе, только не эта информация нужна. А нужно например то что улица Лежневская города Иваново относится к Фрунзенскому району.

Попробовал набрать в яндекс запрос вроде "какой район города Иваново ул. Лежневская", на этот запрос вверху выдачи в сером Выделенном прямоугольнике есть информация о районе. Подумал может быть вытаскивать оттуда, потом оказалось что такая информация выводится не для любых улиц, при этом в выдаче как правило есть сайт от 2gis у которого в снипете вроде как информация о районе есть. При этом если смотреть в  сторону такого парсера эффективность от получения такой информации возможно не сопоставима с временем на реализацию. Кроме того парсинг выдачи не сказать что будет стабильным, а так же потребуется ещё какая то база в которой хотя бы будет список районов для каждого города.

Или может быть всё же есть готовое решение?

Comment: Посмотрите ссылки [здесь](https://qna.habr.com/q/616423)

Comment: думаю готовое решение можно подглядеть у самого яндекса в вашем [запросе](https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=118515&text=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE+%D1%83%D0%BB.+%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%22) про который вы пишете зайдя в инспектор кода и покопавшись в портянке))

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку, что Вы скинули, оказалось к запросу что я отправлял требовалось в конце добавить параметр kind с значением district, вот такая ссылка в конечном счёте получается(только я ключ стёр): https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=MYKEYgeocode=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20119&format=json&lang=ru_RU&kind=district

Comment: Теоретически, данная информация должна быть к коде ОКАТО, который есть в КЛАДР/ФИАС.